# How to fix the "Please select a different payment method" on shopify | paypal ?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, shopify, payment-gateway, online-store

i'm new here i wish you all are doing well.
the thing is that i have started a new online store on shopify and i have integrated the PayPal Express Checkout and i'm still in the 14 days trial .
the problem is when i completed the store settings and everything i wanted to try the checkout as a customer to see if everything is going well but when i click the paypal button (to pay as a costumer) i face this problem that says ( Something went wrong There was a problem with the payment service. Please select a different payment method or try again later . Return to cart ) please any solutions ? 
thanks in advance .
Note : i'm not using any other payment gateway

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually have to have a Plan Selected and a card added to your profile.

https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/testing-checkout-purchase-while-on-a-trial-plan-401423

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with your seller portal since you are still in your trial period. If you do not have a card set up and a plan selected, Shopify will not allow you to follow through with a test payment. Pick a plan, enter your card information, test out the checkout and you can close your trial store down before you get charged for a Shopify plan.